# Why does mysql adds a default timestamp on insert/update even if I did not specify anything?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table that is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (  
    id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    status enum('broken','repaired') NOT NULL,  
    from datetime NOT NULL,  
    until datetime NOT NULL,  
    brought_in timestamp,  
    brought_by varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    repair_status enum('unpayed', 'payed') DEFAULT NULL,  
    payed_when timestamp,    
    delivered_when timestamp,  
    primary key(id)    
);
```

When I create the table if I do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` then I see that the column `brought_in` is defined to have the current timestamp `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE`.
But I did not add such an instruction in my create table.
Why doesn't it let it be empty like the other columns?
Now on every insert or update of another column it adds the current timestamp. I don't want that.
It does not do that with the other columns. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's the default behaviour of the (first) `timestamp` column. Read the documentation: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html). If you don't want this, you have to explicitly tell MySQL.

Comment: Use `brought_in timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,` or some other `default` value and you'll have no automatic properties.

Comment: @ypercube:Really?Why does it do that?Any idea on the logic behind?

Comment: I don't know why the original developers made that choice. They also made the inconsistent choice that `TIMESTAMP` columns are by default `NOT NULL` while all other columns are by default `NULL` ...

Comment: @ypercube:Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: From what I understand, the purpose of `TIMESTAMP` is to track updates, that's the reason for the auto-update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the (first) `timestamp` column. Many more details can be read in the documentation: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

If you don't want this, you have to explicitly tell MySQL when you create the table. You can declare a default value (or default null) and the automatic properties will be supressed. Any of the following will do (with differences in behaviour explained):

---

**Option 1: `not null`** and **`default 0`**

```
brought_in timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,             -- option 1a

brought_in timestamp DEFAULT 0,                      -- option 1b
```

These two options are identical. The column is defined as `NOT NULL` and has a default value of `0`. Note that `TIMESTAMP` is the only datatype that has a default property of `NOT NULL`, **in contrast** with all other datatypes and with the ISO/ANSI standard.

If you try to insert `NULL` in the column, the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is inserted (surprise, another MySQL feature.)

---

**Option 2: `null`** and **`default null`**

```
brought_in timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,              -- option 2a

brought_in timestamp NULL,                           -- option 2b
```

These are identical, they allow `NULL` (and both result in default being `NULL` as well.)

If you try to insert `NULL` in the column, it is allowed and inserted fine (no surprises here.)

---

**Option 3: `null`** and **`default 0`** or some other constant

```
brought_in timestamp NULL DEFAULT 0,                 -- option 3a

brought_in timestamp NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-01',      -- option 3b
```

This is similar to option 2 but has a different default value.

If you try to insert `NULL` in the column, it is allowed and inserted fine, too (no surprises here either.)

Comment: I was wondering is this behavior outside of the SQL standard?I mean how these data types behave aren't they part of the SQL standard?

Comment: Datetimes have been implemented with quite many differences in the various DBMS.

Comment: Can't believe this answer doesn't have more upvotes, +1.