# In MySQL, how can I have non-nullable timestamp column without a default value?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I want a non-nullable `timestamp` column where the inserter is required to specify what the value should be.

The following configuration

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  t timestamp not null
);
```

results in the default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value, while

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  t timestamp not null default null
);
```

results in

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 't'

I want the same behavior that, for example, the `int` column below has:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  i int not null
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the only way is setting the server variable [`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51748/why-does-mysql-adds-a-default-timestamp-on-insert-update-even-if-i-did-not-speci) to `ON` (default is `OFF`).

This will disable the non-standard behaviour of `timestamp` columns regarding `NULL` values:

> If `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` is enabled, the server disables the nonstandard behaviors and handles `TIMESTAMP` columns as follows:
>
> - **It is not possible to assign a `TIMESTAMP` column a value of `NULL` to set it to the current timestamp.** To assign the current timestamp, set the column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or a synonym such as `NOW()`.
> - ...
> - **`TIMESTAMP` columns declared with the `NOT NULL` attribute do not permit `NULL` values.** For inserts that specify `NULL` for such a column, **the result is either an error** for a single-row insert or if strict SQL mode is enabled, or '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is inserted for multiple-row inserts with strict SQL mode disabled. **In no case does assigning the column a value of `NULL` set it to the current timestamp.**